# Why is it showing no output?

Tags: node.js

In my recently viewed, I wanted to list the id of the events which I posted. But if it is more than five, then I just want the last 5 id's which I posted. It is not showing any error, but not giving any result. Is there anything wrong with the code?

**server.js**

```
var express= require('express');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var config=require('./config');
var app= express();
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var lodash= require('lodash');
var underscore= require('underscore');
//var User=require('./database/user')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db',function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log("connected!");
    }
});
//res.json({message:"     " })
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true })); //if false then parse only strings
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));//log all the requests to the console
var api=require('./app/routes/api')(app,express);
app.use('/api',api);
app.get('*',function(req,res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/index.html');
});   // * means any route

app.listen(config.port,function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log("The server is running");
    }
});
```

**api.js**

```
var User= require('../models/user');
var Event=require('../models/event');
var config=require('../../config');

var secret=config.secretKey;
module.exports=function(app,express) {
    var api = express.Router();
    // app.use()

    api.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
        var user = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password

        });

        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.json({
                message: 'User created!'
            });
        });

    });
    api.get('/users', function (req, res) {
        User.find({}, function (err, users) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
           res.json(users);
        });
    });
    api.post('/eventfeed', function (req, res) {
        var event = new Event({
            name: req.body.name,
            location: req.body.location,
            description: req.body.description,
            price: req.body.price,
            rating: req.body.rating
        });

        event.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.json({
                message: 'Event created!'
            });
        });
    });
    api.get('/event', function (req, res) {
        Event.find({}, function (err, event) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.json(event);
        });
    });
api.post('/recentlyviewed',function(req,res){
        User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.body.userid},
            { $push:{"recent": {eventid: req.body.eventid},$each:[],$slice:-5}},
            { upsert :true},
            function(err,user){
                if(err) return err;
                else
                res.json(user);
            });
    });
    return api;
}
```

This is my User Scehma
**event.js**

```
var  UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    username: {type: String,required:true,index:{unique:true}},
    password: {type:String,required:true,select:false },
    favouriteid : [{eventid:String}],
    recent:[{eventid:String}]
```

Comment: If I remove the slice and each, there is an output but when I use this syntax, there always one output i.e { }.

Answer (score 0):

`findByIdAndUpdate` takes just an id as the first argument rather than an object. Checking the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/#up._S_slice) you're also using the $push and $each combination incorrectly, you're supplying the $each and $slice separately when they should be part of the "recent" object and the object you're pushing should be inside the $each array. It should be

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id, {
        $push: {
            "recent": {
                $each: [ {eventid: req.body.eventid} ],
                $slice: -5
            }
        }
    },
    { upsert :true},//etc
```

Comment: Ah, the function is also designed to take a model object so what I thought was the problem before accidentally works (not mentioned in the docs but it's in the code). I spotted your mistake with the slice operator though, which explains why removing it works.

Comment: {
  "name": "MongoError",
  "message": "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $push",
  "$err": "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $push",
  "code": 17287
}

Comment: That doesn't make much sense as the $push isn't part of the query, are you definitely removing the `{` from before the `req.body.id`?